# Can Custom python layers defined in TF be imported to TFJS?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

So, I needed to port the image contrast function available in TF into TFJS for my model since the example given in the documentation to change the contrast was not working, although, now that I bring the new model back into TFJS, the model does not load.

Is there any way to get custom-defined layers in TF to work in TFJS?